# Simple Injector register automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, automapper, simple-injector

I would like to register Automapper with Simple Injector to inject it into the controller:

```
public class MyController : BaseController
{
    private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    private IMappingEngine mappingEngine;

    public PatientController(IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork, IMappingEngine _mappingEngine)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = _unitOfWork;
        this.mappingEngine = _mappingEngine;
    }
}
```

However when I am trying to register it

```
public static void Initialize()
{
    //Code for registering our repository class and DI
    var container = new Container();
    container.Register<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

    container.Register<IMappingEngine, MappingEngine>();

    container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(
        new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

I got an error:

> For the container to be able to create MappingEngine, it should contain exactly one public constructor, but it has 2.
>
> Parameter name: TImplementation.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check the constructor of the MappingEngine and see whether the types injected int MappingEngine registered or not? Also try the below https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/05/12/automapper-and-ioc/

Comment: Also read this https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97 to understand why Simple Injector forces one constructor and how to deal with framework types as exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple Injector can't automatically auto-wire the `MappingEngine` type for you, and it shouldn't, because this is a framework type and framework types should not be auto-wired, as you can read [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97#Framework-types).

Instead, use manual wiring, as follows:

```
var container = new Container();

container.RegisterSingle<IMappingEngine>(Mapper.Engine);
```

Comment: Thanks, that' s exactly what I need, works perfect, you save my life, thanks alot